# I can't make symbols with Ctrl+Alt+(key) and my keyboard doesn't have an Alt Gr key – what do I do?

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, keyboard, kde, keyboard-layout

I'm on a laptop with a bluetooth keyboard connected. When I changed from Windows 7 to Xubuntu 14.04 (now using KDE 4 with it) I could no more use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>(key)</kbd> to make symbols as

```
@£$½¥{[]}
```

I instead have to use <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>(key)</kbd> to make them, which becomes irritating because my bluetooth keyboard has NO <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key.

How can I do so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> acts the same as <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>?

I am using the danish keyboard (default) layout on a German keyboard.

Comment: It should be possible to assign Alt-Gr to another key, like the right control key for example. I do not know how to do it in KDE, just in gnome... anyone?

Comment: There are a few ways, lemme just write a propper answer

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/553710/how-do-i-type-an-%C3%A6-character

Comment: Nope, thats unicode stuff, i want to make @ with Ctrl + Alt + 2 without doing unicode stuff

Comment: I dont even know what that is..