# How do I type an 'æ' character?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I've tried `alt`+`0198`but it doesn't work. I guess that only works in Windows. How do I type it in Ubuntu?

Comment: [This site](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e6/index.htm) lists the Windows shortcut number for æ as 145, so are we talking about the same character?

Comment: @muru I guess I mean 145. I'm not having any luck with your answer by the way :/ `ctrl` + `shift` + `u` + (`e`,`6`)

Comment: When you press Ctrl-Shift-u, do you see a `u` with an underline appear?

Comment: You have to release Ctrl+Shift+U after you finished typing it. Don't hold it down.

Comment: There is a [bug in Ubuntu Gnome](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1246272) with a workaround that breaks ctrl+shift+u. So the best method is to setup a [compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey#Compose_key) and use Compose+a+e --- you can set it to ShiftLock, the less useful key in the universe ;-)

Comment: This is not exactly a duplicate, as the question can be answered by using the Meta key scheme, which is not possible for the linked question (arbitrary Unicode characters). Of course, inputting arbitrary Unicode characters is *one* possible answer for *this* question, but there are legitime and easy others (see my answer here).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Typing unicode is slightly different in Ubuntu.

The key combination is:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, *code*, <kbd>Space</kbd>

However, Windows uses decimal notation while Ubuntu uses Hex notation.

Æ in this case (what 0198 is) is `c6` for Ubuntu. So, you'd do:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>. Release it.
2. Type `c6` (or `00c6`)
3. Press <kbd>Space</kbd>

If you were talking about æ (or 145 on Windows), replace all instances of `c6` with `e6`.

As mentioned by @Graham, you can also use the [compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey). By default, it is <kbd>AltGr</kbd> or <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>. You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd> followed by <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd> to enter an `æ`. I think holding the other shift as well will give you `Æ`. On some keyboard layouts, <kbd>AltGR</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>AltGR</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (below) will also give `æ`.

As mentioned by @DevSolar, if you need to use special characters frequently, you can also use keyboard styles such as English (US) English (international AltGr dead keys). These keys will automatically map certain AltGRs to characters.
[image: Map of keys]

<sup>[(src)](http://ubunuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1767498)</sup>

Comment: On my keyboard `AltGr`+`a` already gives æ.

Comment: On my ubuntu with "US-Intl Algr-Deadkeys" `Alt-z` gives æ

Comment: @Bakuriu. On my keyboard, AltGr+vowel = vowel with acute accent: áéíóú.

Comment: Visualise the keyboard layout and check if the `æ` character is present.

Comment: How am I supposed to hold down all these keys !? `Ctrl+Shift+U+*code*`

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana Read the instructions in the answer. You do **not** hold all of them down at the same time.

Answer (score 21):

Whatever you have set as the [`compose key`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey) then a then e in sequence will produce æ

This solution is much simpler, as you don't have to know the unicode for the character you wish to type. For example [`compose key`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey)  then o then e will produce œ. [`compose key`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey) then c then , (comma) will produce ç and so on.

Comment: @Whaaaaaat go to system settings> Text Entry> Keyboard Settings. You can change the compose key to what you like from there. For example, I have set the RightWindows key as my compose key.

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer. Once you realize how simple and intuitive the compose key method is, you will wonder why you ever bothered with alt-codes and Unicode-codes in the first place… (← see those three dots rolled into one character? Simply do compose: period, period. Oh and the arrow? Compose: <, -.)

Comment: ¡This is a much better solution! ⸘Why is it voted so low‽ ♪ (guess how I made those Unicode characters)

Comment: @Graham Yep, especially for accented characters. I've seen Spanish teachers type accented vowels with alt+numpad on Windows, and even Windows has easier ways of doing this (even though they don't have the wonderful compose key that we do :D).

Answer (score 4):

From [this Ubuntu Forums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1767498): Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> and the Unicode number of the character. In this case, æ is `00e6` (or simply `e6`). `e6` is 230 in decimal, so presumably you were talking about the capital letter (Æ), which is `c6` (198).

Answer (score 4):

If you need such characters frequently, one-shot solutions like composing or going through code points don't really cut it. I would suggest you give one of the "international" US key layouts a try.

I'm German, but prefer (*) US keyboards with the "English (US) English (international AltGr dead keys)" key layout -- at least that's what Mint (an Ubuntu derivative) calls it. For X11, that'd be "-xkblayout us -xkbvariant altgr-intl". Windows calls it "[US International Alternate](http://keyboards.jargon-file.org/altinter.zip)".

It leaves the basic mappings (those available via <kbd>Shift</kbd>-`<key>` etc.) alone, but allows easy accent construction by making `, ', ^ and " "dead" when entered with <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, plus making many international characters directly available via <kbd>AltGr</kbd>:

```
¡²³¤€¼½¾‘’¥×
äåé®þüúíóö«»¬
áßðø¶ø
æ©ñç¿
```

Your "æ", for example, would be <kbd>AltGr</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>. You quickly get used to where those extra characters are, and you don't have to memorize (or look up) character codes.

---

(*): US layout makes `/{[]}\|` much easier to reach, which I welcome since I write code most of the day.

Answer (score 3):

When one needs some specific unicode char one can open KCharSelect and guess it's name there:

[image]

one then can copy-paste that in any application.

Answer (score 3):

If you need "Æ" because you actually write in Norwegian sometimes the most simple would be to activate the Norwegian keyboard layout in Ubuntu's OS settings so that you have two available keyboards layouts, English and Norwegian (f. ex.) and you can quickly switch between them. You can probably also set a keyboard shortcut for swithcing between the keyboard layouts.

Answer (score 2):

There’s another method: [typing using the Meta key](http://fsinfo.noone.org/~abe/typing-8bit.html)

In this case, it’s <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> because the ASCII code (and Unicode) of f is 66hex, and the Unicode of æ is U+00E6, and 66hex + 80hex = E6hex.

You will need to either use xterm with <kbd>Meta</kbd> key configured correctly, or a BSD with [wscons(4)](https://www.mirbsd.org/man4/wscons) text console (not FreeBSD, which has a different one), or a custom keyboard layout (I made one [for Windows (NT 4 and up)](http://www.mirbsd.org/cvs.cgi/~checkout~/contrib/code/Snippets/KBDmir2U.exe?rev=HEAD;content-type=application%2Foctet-stream), one [for the Linux text console](http://www.mirbsd.org/cvs.cgi/contrib/code/Snippets/KBDmir2U.map?rev=HEAD;content-type=text%2Fplain), and three for X11 ([XFree86®](http://www.mirbsd.org/cvs.cgi/contrib/samples/dot.Xmodmap?rev=1.25;content-type=text%2Fplain) (MirBSD), [old X.org](http://www.mirbsd.org/cvs.cgi/contrib/samples/dot.Xmodmap?rev=1.24.2.2;content-type=text%2Fplain) (e.g. Ubuntu hardy), [new X.org](http://www.mirbsd.org/cvs.cgi/contrib/samples/dot.Xmodmap?rev=1.24.4.7;content-type=text%2Fplain) (what you probably have)). The Meta key function is on the <kbd>left Alt</kbd> key for all these layouts (and BSD wscons) *except* the WinNT one, where it is on the <kbd>right Alt</kbd> key. (Your <kbd>left Windows</kbd> key is then usable for the GUI “Alt” key function.) Beware that I also changed the location of the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key for my own convenience (but I’m willing to put up variants without that). This is a graphical depiction of the keyboard layout (XFree86® variant, but the others are almost the same): [image: screenshot of kbd-xf86 from CVS]