# Where to find complete AltGr symbols map per keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I have an italian keyboard layout, if I press this shortcuts I can display *strange* symbols

- <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> = »
- <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> = ×
- etcetera...
  My question is, where can I found a complete visual map of all this AltGr symbols for my italian keyboard layout?

Something similar to https://askubuntu.com/a/553712/23130

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for Text Entry in the Dash (I'm not sure about the Italian localization of that) , select the keyboard and press the symbol with the keyboard.

[image]

Here how it looks for italian keyboard

[image]

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!